# FORTRAN 77 'Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)'

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I'm a Fortran 77 learner, I'm new so don'n know much about Fortran.
Our professor gave us a homework. We suppose to write a program that calculates cos(x**2).
It has a Taylor expansion, so I tried to write some things but It gave me this error:

> ```
>    term = term*((-1)**i)*x**2*i)/fac(2*i)                          
>    1
> ```
>
> Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

The hole program is:

```
        PROGRAM COSX_SQUARE
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER x, n, i
        REAL partial_sum, term

20      PRINT*, 'INPUT THE DEGREE'
        READ*, x
        x = x*180/3.1415

        PRINT*, 'INPUT THE CORRECTION VALUE '
        PRINT*, 'AS A NATURAL NUMBER'

        READ*, n

        i= -1
        term = 1
        partial_sum = term

10      i=i+1
        term = term*((-1)**i)*x**2*i)/fac(2*i)

        partial_sum = partial_sum + term

        IF (i .LT. n) THEN
        GO TO 10
        ELSE
        PRINT*, 'COS', x, 'SQUARE IS = ', partial_sum
        END IF

        GO TO 20

        END
```

Where am I mistaking? And will this program work well?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error does not match your source code! BTW: There are a few thing wrong in your code, I assume these are just copy and paste errors!

Comment: I suppose 'fac' is an external function that returns the factorial? Or is it something else?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question.  OP has admitted that what is posted does not accurately represent the code which is causing the problem.  Stop wasting our time and yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one bracket in your expression!

It should probably read:

```
term = term*(((-1)**i)*x**2*i)/fac(2*i)
```

Comment: I concur.  Once the code has been corrected to split the two un-split statements the compiler will find this fault too.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the bracket but now it gaves me this error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That's related to some missing libraries... But that's a different story ;-) You'll need to give more details. But please - post that in a new question!